# How do I get the comments section to show up?

Tags: comments, templates

My theme does not seem to be showing me the comments section, this is the PHP code I have in my `index.php` file inside the template folder

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <!-- Test if the current post is in category 3. -->
 <!-- If it is, the div box is given the CSS class "post-cat-three". -->
 <!-- Otherwise, the div box is given the CSS class "post". -->
 <?php if ( in_category('3') ) { ?>
           <div class="post-cat-three">
 <?php } else { ?>
           <div class="post">
 <?php } ?>

 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

 <!-- Display the date (November 16th, 2009 format) and a link to other posts by this posts author. -->
 <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></small>

 <!-- Display the Post's content in a div box. -->
 <div class="entry">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>

 <!-- Display a comma separated list of the Post's Categories. -->
 <p class="postmetadata">Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
 </div> <!-- closes the first div box -->

 <!-- Stop The Loop (but note the "else:" - see next line). -->
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>

 <!-- The very first "if" tested to see if there were any Posts to -->
 <!-- display.  This "else" part tells what do if there weren't any. -->
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>

 <!-- REALLY stop The Loop. -->
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome! Did you compare your theme with another one that has comments section? The Codex may be helpful: [Theme_Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look in the twentyTwelve theme. you can see how they get the comments. Look in the full-width.php file and you can see this code

```
 <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

this will call the code to get your comments section. Now you must make sure that your theme has the comments.php. You can also check twentyEleven and twentyTen theme to see the different methods